# Change the "search" keyboard button title

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I am using the default UIKeyBoardType, and it contains a button with a `Search` title. Is there any way to change that title from `Search` to `Dismiss` for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IB you can select the UITextField that you want to change the keyboard for. Then under the Attribute Inspector there is an option "Return Key" You can change the title here.

Comment: Hi, It's not a UITextField, it's just a `UISearchBar`. Also, I am not using IB.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, I saw that afterwards. Then not to my understanding. A normal textField has the attribute .returnKeyType that you can set the enum in code. I do not however see this attribute or anything similar for a UISearchBar. You can change the keyboard type but I think that's it.